# GitLab Cucumber Report

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have just migrated from Jenkins to GitLab for my CI and I can not get the cucumber report as I get it in Jenkins. I believe that GitLab does not have an inbuilt plug in to publish the cucumber report. Would anyone have an idea a plug-in in GitLab that publishes the cucumber report ?

Answer (score 0):

GitLab doesn't have plug-ins like Jenkins, but you can run external commands using `script` directive in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`

See "Getting started" in the [vendor documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/).